# webclient returns valid string from windows server (2008 R2) empty string from workstation (windows 8.1)

Tags: c#, xml, ssis, webclient

When the following code is run from a script component in SSIS (2008 R2) on Windows Server (2008 R2) a string is returned.  When the same code is run on Windows 8.1 it returns an empty string.

When I use put the URL string into chrome on my local system the string is returned. When I put it into IE 11 nothing is returned. I have chrome as my default browser.

```
string url = Dts.Variables["User::URL"].Value.ToString();

//Create a Web Client
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = int.MaxValue;  
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
     //Download the xml document as a string
     xmlDoc = client.DownloadString(url);
}
```

Comment: Could the url be requiring some form of authentication?

Comment: You need to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to find out what is going wrong.  I would compare a good situation against a bad situation.  Either the port number is being blocked by a virus check (or firewall), The url needs to be added to allowed sites in IE, or a proxy server needs to be used.  Sometimes it is helpful to remove cookies from IE where a bad or expired cookie is preventing the connection.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I believe we are pursuing a new non-SSIS implementation option, but I'll keep this information handy or the next time I run into this issue.